# сборка apk при помощи buildozer с импользованием sl4a

Tags: android, python, kivy

Доброго времени суток. Написал простенький скрипт в приложении Qpython3, который говорит, что зарядка подключена и что батарея зарядилась. Qpython использует модуль sl4a т.е.:

```
import sl4a
droid = sl4a.Android()
```

и дальше код..

Это всё прекрасно работает на телефоне (Nexus5).
Решил сделать из этого скрипта приложение независящее от наличия Qpython и т.д.

Посклольку имеется небольшой опыт сборки приложения написанного на питон и в качестве гуи использован `kivy`, то сделал гуи, а внутри кнопка start. Собрал приложение с помощью `buildozer`, предварительно установив `python-android`.
Если устанавливать этот пакет на `python 2.7.10`, то введя:

```
import android
dir(android)
```

нет класса Android

Если устанавливать на `python 3.4.3`, то при импорте вообще вываливается ошибка.

Если проделать тоже самое в Qpython, то видно, что класс Android присутствует.

Нашёл на телефоне sl4a.py закинул в туже папку на компе, импортировал, но при отладке видно, что валятся какие-то ошибки про socket (описан в классе Android в секции **init**):

```
def __init__(self, addr=None):
    if addr is None:
      addr = HOST, PORT
    self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)
    self.client = self.conn.makefile("rw")
    self.id = 0
    if HANDSHAKE is not None:
      self._authenticate(HANDSHAKE)
```

В общем вопрос: можно ли вообще как-то использовать этот модуль для сборки своего приложения (`apk`) или sl4a можно использовать только с Qpython ?

Также пробовал собирать приложение, как описано тут: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android в этом случае установленное приложение вместо 30 метров (при сборке buildozer) занимает 100 метров! Но также не работает.

[видюшка как собирал](https://vk.com/videos50654483?section=recoms&z=video50654483_171674036%2Fdfe5e14a4bcc2b6976%2Fpl_updates)

Comment: попробуйте пустой проект собрать и задеплоить - посмотрите какие ошибки повылазиют, может и не в классе дело

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылки на оригинальные сайты:

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html

http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Там описаны инструкции в несколько строк.

Пока сам делал по различным статьям и урокам - возникали накладки. Сделал по инструкциям разработчиков и всё стало собираться и деплоиться.